# jscript to run at window.onload AND item.onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jscript to load a string in to several elements of an array, then display the useful element in html.

There's a pulldown menu that causes the string to change. So, I need the function to be re-run when that happens.

I have been able to successfully display the element using window.onload

and, I have been able to successfully display the element AFTER the pulldown menu has been changed.

But, I can't seem to display the element with window.onload and subsequently after item.onchage

If anyone has any suggestions, I'd be grateful.

Here is the code that works for window.onload

```
window.onload = function() {
    var selectedOptionId = jQuery('select').val();
    var optionPartNumber = jQuery('input[name="OptID_' + selectedOptionId + '"]').val();

    //loads the string in to an array and returns the 2nd element
    var optionPartNumber = optionPartNumber.split(".")[1];
    document.getElementById("MASNUM").innerHTML=optionPartNumber;
}
```

Here is the code that works for pulldown.onchange

```
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery('.dropdownimage-format select').on('change', function(){
   var selectedOptionId = jQuery('select').val();
   var optionPartNumber = jQuery('input[name="OptID_' + selectedOptionId + '"]').val();

    var optionPartNumber = optionPartNumber.split(".")[1];
    document.getElementById("MASNUM").innerHTML=optionPartNumber;
  });
```

In both cases, the element is displayed in html by

```
    <a id="MASNUM">
```

Comment: Put the code into a named function, so you can write it once and call it from both places.

Comment: Your brackets aren't balanced in the second code snippet. Are they balanced in the real code? Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: @barmar I think that's just the stackoverflow codeblock messing with the display. It's balanced where I copied from. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't look like SO changed anything, I think you just forgot to paste the closing brackets. But I can't see any other reason why the two codes wouldn't work together, there's nothing that would cause them to conflict.

Comment: Both of them work together fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/q6fr0jhn/2/

Comment: @barmar not sure what I did wrong. Probably just too much weekend leaking in to my Friday. I'm going to compare what I have in my .js file side by side with your working jsfiddle and see what I've got going on. Thanks for validating it's just me and not the code.

Comment: @Barmar Apologies for the delay. I was pulled away from this task for a few days. After revisiting, you are correct. Setting both as a function fixed the issue. It is working properly now. Thanks.